# Как сделать такой же переход между страницами?

Tags: javascript, html, css

понравился [такой](https://lmpixels.com/wp/aveo/#home) переход между страницами. Там вроде все страницы изначально скрыты, при нажатии она открывается с анимацией. Не знаю как это осуществить
[Ссылка на сайт](https://lmpixels.com/wp/aveo/#home)

Comment: скачай сайт и замени своим текстом и всё поменяй фон и прочее - так себе но ни кто не докапается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вешаете обработчик на переход. К примеру отслеживаете изменение `window.location.hash`

Если происходит изменение применяете класс (css) к примеру к body, в котором описана анимация появления.

Про анимации можно почитать тут https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp